# sorting component-wise multi value (SIMD) array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, sse, simd

I'm trying to find an `O(n∙log(n))` sorting method to sort several arrays simultaneously so that an element in a multi-value array will represent elements from 4 different single value arrays and the sorting method would sort the multi-value elements.

For example:
For a given 4 single value arrays `An`, `Bn`, `Cn` and `Dn`,
I'd set a new array `Qn`
so that `Qᵢ = [ Aᵢ Bᵢ Cᵢ Dᵢ ]`.
`Qᵢ` may be changed during the process so that `Qᵢ = [ Aaᵢ Bbᵢ Ccᵢ Ddᵢ ]`
where `aᵢ`, `bᵢ`, `cᵢ` and `dᵢ` are index lists
and of course that `Qᵢ ≤ Qᵢ₊₁ = [ Aaᵢ₊₁ Bbᵢ₊₁ Ccᵢ₊₁ Ddᵢ₊₁ ]` so that `Aaᵢ ≤ Aaᵢ₊₁`, `Bbᵢ ≤ Bbᵢ₊₁` and so on.
The motivation is to use SIMD intructions of course to benefit from this structure to separately sort the 4 arrays.

I tried to use a SIMD comparer (`_mm_cmplt_ps` for example) and a masked swap (`_mm_blendv_ps` for example)
to make a modified version of traditional sorting algorithms (quick sort, heap sort, merge sort etc)
but I always encounter the problem that in theory there appear to be `O(n∙log(n))` steps in the decision tree.
And so, a decision, whether if to set a pivot (quick sort) or whether if to exchange a parent with one of its children (heap sort)
is not correct for all of the whole 4 components all together at the same time (and thus, the next step - go right or left - is incorrect).

For now i only have `O(n²)` methods working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant: http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/1/1454171.pdf

Comment: @PaulR n is considered to be very big (coordinates of a very dense mesh). I tackled this article earlier. It talks about general sorting (a single array in a SIMD structure)

Comment: @PaulR, that looks like an interesting paper I need to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as though a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) is the answer to the question that you asked, since the position of the comparators is not data dependent. [Batcher's bitonic mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) is O(n log<sup>2</sup> n).

Comment: Thanks! that certainly is what I was looking for